# How to add numbered list style in div tag

Tags: javascript, css, css-counter

I have `div` tags with `span` tag. How to add numbered list for the `div` tag using classname in CSS or JavaScript

```
<div id="editsum">
    <div class="esum"><span id="1430568488933" class="tbold">nde</span></div>
    <div class="esum"><span id="1430568576033" class="tbold">ca</span></div>
    <div class="esum"><span id="1430568582173" class="tdel">tim</span></div>
    <div class="esum"><span id="1430568582173" class="tins">Ó</span></div>
    <div class="esum"><span id="1430914284123" class="tdel">non</span></div>
    <div class="esum"><span id="1430914309275" class="tdel">cu</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understant what you want. Can you edit your question with an example ? (and maybe a JSFiddle)

Comment: Why not put a list around it? `<ol><li><div><span></span></div></li><li>...</li></ol>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/72071kaf/1/

Comment: Not possible to change anything in HTML file. This is client requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to output a numbered list, the best approach is to make use of `<ol>` tags but if you can't modify your HTML and still need to output as a numbered list, you can make use of CSS counters to achieve the numbered list behavior.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: esum;
}
.esum {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: esum;
  padding: 10px;
}
.esum:before {
  content: counter(esum)".";
}
```

```html
<div class="esum"><span id="1430568488933" class="tbold">nde</span>
</div>
<div class="esum"><span id="1430568576033" class="tbold">ca</span>
</div>
<div class="esum"><span id="1430568582173" class="tdel">tim</span>
</div>
<div class="esum"><span id="1430568582173" class="tins">Ó</span>
</div>
<div class="esum"><span id="1430914284123" class="tdel">non</span>
</div>
<div class="esum"><span id="1430914309275" class="tdel">cu</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly you given a solution for my question.

Comment: Happy to help mate. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the hollow tick mark on the left side of the answer. That is the way of marking a problem as solved :)

Comment: Yes, sure. I will contact if i have any doubt :-)

Answer (score 2):

**CSS**

```
.esum {
  display: list-item;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

> Add the above **CSS** to you CSS File

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t91uv3tm/1/)

Comment: @kaliaperumal.p can you create a fiddle with that problem because it works fine in my Fiddle.